# Applescript to resort piles of numbers

Tags: numbers, applescript, rename

I'm trying to resort a bunch of numbers with Applescript. I'm very new to the language and I thought I'd ask you for help.

I have a group of numbers which looks like this in my TextEdit file:

```
v 0.186472 0.578063 1.566364
v -0.186472 0.578063 1.566364
v 0.335649 0.578063 1.771483
```

What i need is a script that resorts these numbers, making it appear like this:

```
(0.186472, 0.578063, 1.566364), 
(-0.186472, 0.578063, 1.566364),
(0.335649, 0.578063, 1.771483),
```

So after each number, there has to be a comma, and always the three numbers on one line have to be put into brackets (). finally there has to be another comma after every bracketed group of three and the `v` before every line has to be deleted.

I've only so far managed to get rid of every "v" using:

```
set stringToFind to "v"
set stringToReplace to ""
```

But now im stuck and I'm hoping for help.

Comment: Hello! It would help if you could surround your code examples with indention or backticks, so they're shown in a fixed-width font and are easier to edit and copy/paste. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Followup questions should be asked in a new question. Please ask it there and remove the update here and you will be helped. I'll remove this comment afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find and replace strings in AppleScript the native way is using `text item delimiters`. There are a fixed number of values separated by spaces (or tabs) on each line, using `text item delimiters`, `text items`and string concatenation we can solve your problem.

I've added an addition linefeed in front and at the back of the string to show that lines that doesn't contain 4 words are ignored.

```
set theString to "
v 0.186472 0.578063 1.566364
v -0.186472 0.578063 1.566364
v 0.335649 0.578063 1.771483
"
set theLines to paragraphs of theString

set oldTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters


repeat with i from 1 to count theLines
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {space, tab}
    if (count of text items of item i of theLines) = 4 then
        set theNumbers to text items 2 thru -1 of item i of theLines
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
        set item i of theLines to "(" & (theNumbers as string) & "),"
    else
        set item i of theLines to missing value
    end if
end repeat

set theLines to text of theLines
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set newString to theLines as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTIDs
return newString
```

Comment: thank you very much! works like a charm! however i think i encountered a small problem. the code seems to return all the negative values as positive. i'm sure that's an easy fix, yet my skills are to limited to detect and solve the problem. any help?

Comment: I've updated the post Järv, It is working with `text items` instead of  `words` now and preserves the leading hyphen for negative values.